# Poner titulo transparente cuando se expande la toolbar en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

He generando una activity usando la plantilla `scroll content` de android studio, me encuentro que cuando se expande `CollapsingToolbarLayout`, el texto de la `Toolbar` se muestra grande y permanente.

Me gustaría que cuando se expande el color del texto sea transparente, es decir que efectué una transición `fadeOut` y cuando se colapse `fadeIn`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me he encontrado con una solución si usar código.

En layout en elemento `CollapsingToolbarLayout` se puede usar las propiedades `app:expandedTitleTextAppearance`y `app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance`

pero una perculidad no se le puede asignar directamente el color, antes se debe definir los estilos

en `styles.xml` definir

```
<style name="ExpandedToolbar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">32sp</item>
</style>
<style name="CollapsedToobar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Y ahora en `CollapsingToolbarLayout` le asignamos

```
app:expandedTitleTextAppearance="@style/ExpandedToolbar"
app:collapsedTitleTextAppearance="@style/CollapsedToobar"
```

Obtendremos el efecto `fadeOut` a expandir y `fadeIn` al colapsar la toolbar

En código java no ser como se hace, si alguien quiere complementar, edite la respuesta.

**Update**
Veo que el color a `@color:android/transparent` de blanco pasa a gris antes de desvanecer, la razón es que `transparent = #000000` por solucionar eso, si el texto de la barra es blanco su transparente es `#00FFFFFF`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]